# Get syncfusion Schedule data on a specific cell in Blazor

Tags: asp.net, blazor, scheduler, blazor-server-side, syncfusion-blazor

I am new in SynFusion and Blazor. I read The Synfusion Document and I find myself in situation that I want to get the synfusion cell data and pass data in a Radzen dialogservice. First I have to get the Synfusion Scheduler cell Data . Which Event may I have get that?

For example ScheduleEvents OnCellClick I get Start Date and End Date.But I have to click the empty cell. Now if I click on a cell that have data and showing someone appointment I want to edit so I have to get the data for example I show in a picture of my sfschedule in below to explain:

[image]

If I click "Kevin sick 2 hours off" I could not get data and

```
<ScheduleEvents TValue="AppointmentData" OnPopupOpen="@OnPopupOpen" OnCellClick="OnCellClickAsync" >
```

I am talking about the OnCellClick .

```
<SfSchedule TValue="AppointmentData"   SelectedDateChanged="CommandDateChanged" Width="100%" Height="600px" EnableAutoRowHeight="true" SelectedDate="@DateTime.Now" DateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" @bind-CurrentView="@CurrentView">
        
        <ScheduleResources>
            <ScheduleResource TItem="ResourceData" TValue="int" DataSource="@ProjectData" Field="Id" TextField="Text" ColorField="Color">

            </ScheduleResource>
        </ScheduleResources>
        <ScheduleEvents TValue="AppointmentData" OnPopupOpen="@OnPopupOpen" OnCellClick="OnCellClickAsync" > </SfSchedule>
```

And here is my OnCellClick of C#

```
 public async Task OnCellClickAsync(CellClickEventArgs args)
    {
      
        var parameters2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters2.Add("StartDate", args.StartTime.Date.ToString());
        parameters2.Add("EndDate", args.StartTime.Date.ToString());
        var notificationMessage = new Radzen.NotificationMessage();
        notificationMessage.Severity = Radzen.NotificationSeverity.Success;
        notificationMessage.Duration = 4000;
    }
```

You can see on CellClickEventArgs I can get start date and end date of current cell. But that is only where there is no data. I want to update and that's why I want to get cell data. How can I get current cell data as per the picture I have shown?

Comment: I think OnEventClick this event may be the soulution of my problem but how I pass The AppointmentData object can you have any idea

Comment: I think OnEventClick(EventClickArgs<AppointmentData> args)args.Event.StartTime  I get the data like this

Answer (score 1):

You can get the event details on **OnEventClick** event, please refer to the following UG. You can access your event details on **Event**.
https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/scheduler/events/#oneventclick

If you want to get the event details on OnCellClick event, you can use **GetEvents** method using which can can get all the events available in that cell.

```
    public async Task OnCellClick(CellClickEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        List<AppointmentData> events = await 
            ScheduleRef.GetEvents(args.StartTime, args.EndTime);
    }
```